# I want the string name of any Powershell variable

Tags: powershell, psobject

I would like to pass the string name of any Powershell variable to any function requiring a simple -Name parameter string e.g. $anyvar1 as a usable string with value **'anyvar1'**. A function will use that variable's name literal **var1** in this type of statement, which removes $var1:

```
      param (
            [string] $varName
            )
  try
    {
      Remove-Variable -Name $varName
    }
  catch{
  # trap any message if the variable doesn't exist
    }
  }
```

I need this to be dynamic so if I pass any old variable to a function like this trivial example e.g.

```
     RemoveVar $anyvar1
```

it will just get the name, not like this where a string literal is used. T

```
     RemoveVar -Name '$anyvar1'
```

The second approach works, if the $ is stripped off the name literal and so on, but has be constructed.

So any function needing a simple -Name string parameter needs to get that name from the variable $anyvar1 **object itself**.

Get-Variable requires a simple name to get a variable as an object and thereby access any of its properties, including Name, but the chicken and egg situation occurs.

So a one-liner to get the object name property from any variable is needed. If it is of a particular scope, need to get the scope as well

So,

```
$Global:anyvar1="SOMEVALUE"
...
...
# all done with $Global:anyvar1
# figure out its name
$varName = Get-VarName -inputObject $Global:anyvar1   ??????

Remove-Variable -Name $varName -Scope Global
 # $varName would contain the literal Global:anyvar1.
```

the function Get-VarName does not exist AFAICT - but there must be a way to

- Create a variable either the simple way or the Set-Variable way
- Use the variable for whatever
- in the above example, get rid of the variable **by name** when no longer needed etc.

Obviously any locally declared variables, or script level, go out of scope and so on, but $Global variables and others of that sort may need to be explicitly removed.

In C#, I would probably have used **nameof(anyvar1)** to do this, so something simple like that?

Any help is appreciated.  It is probably blindingly obvious but I am not getting it.

Comment: there is no `nameof` in PowerShell, whish there would be... you could for example get all variables where the value of `$var` is a reference of the function's argument (`Get-Variable | Where-Object { [object]::ReferenceEquals($_.Value, $var) }`) and from there you can determine the variable name, however that would output all variables having that reference not only the one you were expecting. what about just pass the variable name without `$` to the function? then there is no need for single quotes

Comment: if the issue was about auto-completion, `Remove-Variable` already provides it built-in, with the `$global:` example `rv anyvar1` would work fine

Comment: One funky way might be to wrap the variable in a script block and then inspect the AST - not sure if that really offers any benefits over just quoting the variable name though… ```$var1 = "aaa"; $var2 = { $var1 }; $name =  $var2.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements.Expression.VariablePath.UserPath``` - the ```$name``` variable will contain the string “var1”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Santiago has already provided helpful pointers in the comments; let me elaborate:

- PowerShell currently (PowerShell 7.4.x) has *no* equivalent to C#'s [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) feature.

  - [GitHub issue #9626](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9626) is a long-standing feature request to add one, but there hasn't been meaningful activity in a long time.
- `$varName` is a reference to the *value* of the variable named `varName`, and therefore doesn't support reflecting on the *variable itself*.

  - The only exception is in *assignments*: in `$varName = ...` `$varName` indeed identifies the target *variable*.
  - As an aside: POSIX-compatible shells avoid this ambiguity by requiring that *no* `$` be used in assignments (`varName=...`).
- The PowerShell-idiomatic way is indeed to pass the *names* of variables as a way to identify a *variable object* for other commands to operate on, via the `*-Variable` cmdlets (e.g. [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) and [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable), which of necessity also operate on variable *names*).

  - E.g., `Get-Variable -ValueOnly HOME` retrieves the value of the automatic `$HOME` variable, and, likewise, the [common `-OutVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable) expects the *name* of the output variable as its argument; e.g.,  `-OutVariable out` captures the output in variable `$out`.
- Therefore, I suggest you use the same approach, in combination with a custom argument-completer to make tab-completion of existing variable names easier.

---

**Windows PowerShell** solution, using an [`ArgumentCompleter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ArgumentCompleterAttribute) attribute for tab-completion in combination with a [`ValidateScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) for argument validation:

```bash
function Invoke-Foo {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ArgumentCompleter({ 
      param($command, $parameter, $wordToComplete)
      @((Get-Variable).Name) -like "$wordToComplete*" 
    })]
    [ValidateScript({
      if ($_ -notin (Get-Variable).Name) { throw "'$_' is not the name of an existing variable." }
      $true
    })]
    [string] $VarName
  )

  # Sample output.
  [pscustomobject] @{
    VarName = $VarName
    # Get the variable's value; note the indirection: the target
    # variable name is specified via the value of *another* variable,
    # $VarName
    VarValue = Get-Variable -ErrorAction Ignore $VarName -ValueOnly
  }

}
```

**[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) solution**, via a custom `class` implementing [`IValidateSetValuesGenerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator), in combination with the [`ValidateSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute) attribute, which *combines* tab-completion with argument validation:

```bash
class ExistingVariableNames : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator {
  [string[]] GetValidValues() { return (Get-Variable).Name }
}

function Invoke-Foo {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [ValidateSet([ExistingVariableNames])]
    [string] $VarName
  )

  # Sample output.
  [pscustomobject] @{
    VarName = $VarName
    VarValue = Get-Variable -ErrorAction Ignore $VarName -ValueOnly
  }

}
```

Note:

- If you type `Invoke-Foo <tab>`, the names of existing variables are offered for completion, and `Invoke-Foo H<tab>` offers all variables whose name starts with `H`.
- Additionally, passing the name of a non-existing variable is prevented.

Comment: OK, so until NameOf gets added to Powershell, which has been requested, I will just have to be patient.  I was trying to use this within another function which could trap misbehavior, but it is pretty unlikely for Remove-Variable anyway (the particular example).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the existing feature request, @Allen - I've added a link to it to the answer.

Comment: As a side comment, the Set-Variable cmdlet provides the reverse transform.  The -name parameter is given the variable name without the dollar sign, and operates on the variable named in the usual way.